Por que no funciona el botón?
Estoy haciendo una practica en Android Studio con Kotlin, el cual no ejecuta el método que estoy poniendo, si el campo nombre esta vacío me debería mostrar un mensaje, si no me muestra la otra activity.
Este es mi XML:
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnChangeActivity"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/btn_Enviar"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
    android:text="@string/tv_Title"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvName"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:hint="@string/hint"
    android:autofillHints="Name"/>

</RelativeLayout>

Esta es mi clase de la activity:
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
private lateinit var main: ActivityMainBinding

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    enableEdgeToEdge()
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main)) { v, insets ->
        val systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
        v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom)
        insets
    }

    main = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater);

    main.btnChangeActivity.setOnClickListener { checkValue() }
}

private fun checkValue()
{
    if(main.etName.text.toString().isEmpty())
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "The name cannot be empty.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else
    {
        val intent = Intent(this, ShowNameActivity::class.java);
        intent.putExtra("name", main.etName.text.toString());
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}

Apenas estoy comenzando a aprende este lenguaje, pero no entiendo por que no ejecuta el método checkValue, si se supone que si lo estoy llamando cuando hago click en el botón.
En el gradle active el viewBinding:
android {
namespace = "com.example.hello_world"
compileSdk = 34
viewBinding{
    enable = true;
}


No se mucho, pero, estableces main, luego la view, y ahí no deberías hacer un setContentView(view) ?? tienes uno antes, pero no entiendo que se quiere lograr con ese. Esto ocurre durante el onCreate

Cierto, se me había olvidado quitar esa línea, la había puesto porque en un foro encontre que se ponía. Lo que quiero lograr es usar los controles de la acti9vity del poroyecto, se supone que cuando activo el ````viewBinding``` ya puedo usar en este caso el botón y el editText que hay en mi activity

Nunca usé View Binding, pero comenzaría revisando la documentación. Si no usaras esta característica, recuerda que puedes acceder a las vistas del layout mediante findViewById(R.id.x) donde x es el id de la vista.
Esto es lo que dice:

To set up an instance of the binding class for use with an activity,
perform the following steps in the activity's onCreate() method:

Call the static inflate() method included in the generated binding class. This creates an instance of the binding class for the activity
to use.
Get a reference to the root view by either calling the getRoot() method or using Kotlin property syntax.
Pass the root view to setContentView() to make it the active view on the screen.


En español, llamas al método inflate de la clase generada automáticamente, obtienes una referencia a la vista raíz y se la pasas al método setContentView de tu Activity.
La documentación provee un ejemplo muy simple y fácil de entender:
private lateinit var binding: ResultProfileBinding

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ResultProfileBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    val view = binding.root
    setContentView(view)
}

Lo que estás haciendo mal es llamar setContentView con tu archivo XML. Según el ejemplo, tu Activity debería verse así:
private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    val view = binding.root
    setContentView(view)

    enableEdgeToEdge()
    // Creo que "view" debería tener una referencia al RelativeLayout
    ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(view) { v, insets ->
        val systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
        v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom)
        insets
    }

    binding.btnChangeActivity.setOnClickListener { checkValue() }
}


Ya decía yo que ese setContentView estaba mal ubicado. Pero no se mucho del tema, asi que no me atrevi mas que a comentar

View Binding es un avance con respecto a findViewById por varios motivos: reducir el riesgo de NPE, garantizar seguridad de tipos, mejorar el rendimiento, simplicidad del código, reducir el riesgo de errores. Ver la misma documentación de Android, o ver por ejemplo este post. Y, hay más avances, porque el mismo View Binding quedó enormemente superado por Jetpack Compose. Sobre todo en proyectos nuevos, es recomendable usarlo.

@A.Cedano yo creo que View Binding no es lo que fue superado por Jetpack Compose, sino la creación de interfaces por medio de archivos XML directamente. Me parece que hicieron bien al apostar por la programación declarativa teniendo en cuenta que la alternativa (React native) la usa

Sí @Mateo, es como dices, pero en eso queda comprendido View Binding porque con Jetpack Compose puedes decir adiós a los XML para manejar componentes gráficos.

Hola, muchas gracias por responder, cambie el código a como tu lo comentas en la respuesta, pero siguió sin funcionar, al final opte por referenciar los componentes del layout como tu dices, con findViewById(R.id.x)
